# JAR works locally, but hangs fails in Docker container - Apache-POI

Tags: java, docker, apache-poi

I have a JAR that gets an external XLSX resource and opens a workbook with Apache-POI

```
  FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("sheets/template.xlsx");
  Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
```

When I run the JAR locally, everything works smoothly, however, when I execute the JAR in Docker, the JAR seems to hang when it tries to create the workbook, no exceptions thrown, nothing.

Any ideas? I can provide more info.

Edit more info:

The /sheets/ directory is present in the root directory of my container:

[image]

I should mention that if I run java -jar app.jar on my local machine, everything works smoothly with the following file structure:

```
.
+-- app.jar
+-- sheets/
    +-- template.xlsx
```

Comment: More information is needed about how you run Docker. Is /sheets/template.xlsx accessible (I.E. permissions, does it already exist?) inside your docker container, or mapped with a volume? Also, you can try docker inspect to see if anything was logged?

Comment: I added more info about my container mapping. The JAR doesn't appear to hang or crash according to docker inspect and docker top, should I post that info?

Answer (score 2):

The path to the file seems fishy to me. "/sheets/template.xlsx" would mean the root of the environment you are in, but according to your output, you aren't in the root of the container, but instead in /usr/src/app. Try taking out the "/" so the string would be "sheets/template.xlsx", or change it to be the absolute path to the directory "/usr/src/app/sheets/template.xlsx".

On your box (outside of docker) does app.jar live in the root? If so that would explain everything.

Comment: My above code was incorrect, I'm actually using a fileInputStream and not a resource stream:

```
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("sheets/template.xlsx");
```

This works locally with the above file structure, I tried ("/usr/src/app/sheets/template.xlsx") and it still hangs, I think you're onto something though, I'll keep trying stuff.

Comment: I get a FileNotFoundException when the template.xlsx isn't pathed correctly,  so the program can find it, it just hangs when it tries to create a workbook for some reason. Again, this works outside of a container.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, there's a memory leak in my program, and it was exceeding my allocated docker memory on my local machine. Docker wouldn't tell me locally, but Heroku let me know:

[image]